# Expose different modules for different build targets (electron app vs. web)

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron, node.js-fs, browserfs

I have an app that I want build as an Electron app (using electron-builder) or build for deployment to a web server. With the Electron app, I have the app (from inside the Electron renderer) read and write from the FileSystem (using Node's FS). I want to use BrowserFS instead when in a browser environment. How can I follow the following pseudocode so that it works in browsers and with Electron?

```
if ( inside_node & fs_available ){
  require(fs);
}else{
  require(browserfs);
  fs.customBrowserfsFunction();
}
fs.doSomething();
```

Comment: You might want to look at [dependency injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection) patterns. Doing it this way lets you abstract implementation behind an "interface" (a common set of functions between multiple implementations), allowing you to swap between implementations without rewriting your code or your code having to know about specific implementations. In this case, you create two modules with a `doSomething()` that uses Node FS on one, and Browser FS on the other. Then your build process could swap out one for the other depending on your target environment.

Comment: Since BrowserFS implements Node's FS API I don't have to worry about 2 different APIs. I just need the part inside the `if` expression.

Comment: @Dr.Vortex - I believe you'll find that assertion to be a bit on the naive side. The API calls may be the same, but configuring each is quite a different story. Joseph is correct from a SE point of view.

Comment: Additionally, depending on the app, I believe you'll end up with two code bases. That's a common outcome with these scenarios.

Comment: I've actually worked on BrowserFS myself some, and find that it supports almost all of Node's API calls. I'm not using any of the unimplemented ones, so I don't believe I have any API interface issues.